# automatically appends string in strcat function

Tags: c++, c

I am having a problem with strcat() function. Please explain me how that function works.

```
char a[] = "AT";
char x[] = "KA";
char y = 'X';
sen(a);
s = strcat(a, "+CMGF=");
sen(s);
s = strcat(s, "\r\n");
sen(s);
s = strcat(s, &y);
sen(s);
getch();
return 0;
```

S is a glopal character pointer & sen() is a function just to print the data of the contained string. Now the final value of s is "AT+CMGF=\r\nXKA".

It automatically appends the x array at the last in the s, though i haven't written code of it.

Why is it so?  Please explain me

Comment: You have undefined behaviour. What your program does should be of no concern.

Comment: This is clearly an undefined behavior

Comment: You've allocated arrays of size 3 and are concatenating beyond what it can hold. This leas to Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Another problem. `strcat` requires null-terminated `char` strings for _both_ parameters. The last `strcat` is passed the address of a single `char` variable `y`. You need to fix that.

Comment: @KaranShah These links will help you understand [Undefined Behaviour](http://c-faq.com/ansi/undef.html) and [why accessing array elements thus leads to to UB](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/non0based.html). I'd really recommend you to read some proper C or C++ book; nothing can come close to reading a book to fully understand concepts thoroughly instead of scouring the internet which is littered with half cooked information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are in the realm of undefined behavior.  More specifically, what it is doing is this:

```
char a[] = "AT";
char x[] = "KA";
char y = 'X';
s = strcat(a, "+CMGF="); // a is a constant string, so this is NOT fine.  You should be calling s = strcat(s, a) and then s = strcat(s, "+CMGF=")
s = strcat(s, "\r\n"); // "\r\n" = "\r\n\0", so it is also fine
s = strcat(s, &y); // y is a char, and is NOT null-terminated, so it is NOT fine
```

It just so happened that the compiler you are using placed `y` and `x` side by side in the section of memory, so `strcat` is operating until it finds the first null-terminator.  And all of this is assuming that `s` has enough space allocated for it to hold all of these concatenations (if not, you are in another realm of undefined behavior).

To correct all of your known problems:

```
char s[100] = {0}; // showing declaration of s of sufficient size
char a[] = "AT";
char x[] = "KA";
char y[] = "X";

sen(s); // shows empty string
s = strcat(s, a); // append a to empty s
s = strcat(s, "+CMGF="); // append "+CMGF=" to the end of new s
sen(s); // will now show "AT+CMGF="
s = strcat(s, "\r\n"); // add "\r\n"
sen(s); // will now show "AT+CMGF=\r\n"
s = strcat(s, y); // append y
sen(s); // will now show "AT+CMGF=\r\nX"
```

Comment: Thanks to all to help me to solve this problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

`char a[] = "AT"` will create a string that is exactly 3 characters long. When you then `strcat` something else to it, it writes into the memory after the `a` variable. Which just happens to be some unused space before `x`. [Technically, what happens when you write outside space of `a` is undefined behaviour, and there is absolutely no guarantee that the `KA` from `x` actually is just that precise distance from `a`, or that the code doesn't crash in some way - undefined behaviour means that the C++ standard doesn't explain what will happen, and the compiler and/or runtime library is allowed to crash or behave in a way that "isn't what you expect" in some other way during such behaviour - ANYTHING that your system could possibly do is allowed when UB is invoked]

Make sure that the destination string of `a` is BIG ENOUGH to hold your string, and you won't have that problem.

Comment: I think you meant destination string `s`, not `a`.  He is storing all of this in `s`.

Comment: No, `s` == `a`, as `strcat` returns the destination string.

Comment: Nope, he states that `s` is a global character pointer (thus, it is not the same as `a` - `a` is a pointer to a constant string).  That is, if he leaves his first `strcat` as is, he will be writing to undeclared memory.  `s` must be declared large enough for the entire operation ... `a` is fine as it is - as long as he doesn't try to write to it, as he is doing in his first `strcat`.

Comment: `s = strcat(a, "...")` will make `s` point at `a`. Otherwise, it won't compile. If `s` is initialized or otherwise pointing at some other location, that will be lost.

Comment: I think you are missing my point.  `a` points to a constant string.  The first `strcat` attempts to change `a` (dangerous) and point `s` to the modified a.  He doesn't need to make sure `a` is big enough, he needs to make sure `s` is big enough and **not** attempt to modify a constant string.  That is, he needs to operate on `s`.

Comment: No, `a` is not a constant string, but yes, if the first step is `strcpy(s, a)`, then we could make `s` a string that is large enough to hold the entire string, as a reasonable alternative.

Comment: If not, you would need to declare `a` as `char a[SOME_SUFFICIENT_SIZE] = "AT";`  Since his desired output is to `s`, it makes no sense to modify `a` (which is implicitly declared as `char[3]`).  "constant string" is the wrong wording, but he should not be modifying `a` with the way he has it declared.

Comment: Well, then he should use `strcpy(s, a)` first, not `s = strcat(...)`.

Comment: If `s` is already null-terminated (e.g. if `s` is initialized to be all 0's), it won't matter as it will do the same thing.  If `s` is not initialized, then yes, `strcpy`/`strncpy` would be required.

Comment: Will need to copy `a` into `s` some way, either way.

Comment: However, I wasn't trying to "make good code", I was trying to answer the actual question in the OP's post.